# ZipFile: Extracting a ZipFile coming from AU or India in Python encrypted by a password

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am in France and when trying to extract with the python ZipFile module encrypted zip files coming from Australia or India, files that were encrypted with WINZIP, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 719, in _get_decompressor
    _check_compression(compress_type)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 699, in _check_compression
    raise NotImplementedError("That compression method is not supported")
NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported
```

I was told the sender started by compressing the file with 7-Zip and then added encryption with Winzip, so I asked her to send the file doing both the compressing and the encryption with Winzip but I get the same error message.

Prior to the encryption the sender only compressed the file with 7-Zip with no password and the extraction worked correctly with the same code.

Any ideas?

The python code used is the following:

```
with ZipFile(self.DIR_ATT + att) as zipObj:
    listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
    print(listOfFileNames)

    for file in listOfFileNames:
        print("FILE:", file)

        if str(att.strip(".zip") + "/SR1000C01A") in file:
            print("FILE FOUND")
            print("password:", password)
            zipObj.extract(file, path=self.DIR_ATT, pwd=password.encode())
            zipObj.close()
            df = pd.read_csv(self.DIR_ATT + file)
```

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: After further investigation, the files are extracted correctly in the designated path but the error message persists and makes the python script crash.

Comment: I am under WSL2 but the script is also running on windows and I get the same error.

Comment: Winzip uses AES encryption which isn't supported by the `zipfile` module.

Comment: Which free application should I recommend the sender to use for his encryption?

Comment: Does a python module allow extraction for files compressed with Winzip using AES encryption?